# Fail to run the R code in order to simulate random samples

Tags: r

What I need to do is to draw 1000 random samples of poisson distribution for which n=100, lambda=6

As far as I understand the code like this should do it:

```
 taskpois <- function(size, leng){
  for (i in 1:leng){
    randompois <- rpois(size, 6)
    taskmlepois[i] <- mean(randompois)
  }
  return(taskmlepois)
 }

tasksample <- taskpois(size=100, leng=1000)
```

But after I run it nothing happens. Moreover after that I can't write and run commands in the Console any more as there is no more ">" sign at the beginning of the lines and R starts to collapse.

Do I somehow get wrong how the code I wrote functions or it is just the wrong code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you run `taskpois` function, doesn't it return error message:

```
Error in taskmlepois[i] <- mean(randompois) : 
  object 'taskmlepois' not found
```

...? It should because you did not initialize the `taskmlepois` variable, so you cannot assign values to it!

The code below will work:

```
taskpois <- function(size, leng){
  taskmlepois <- NULL
  for (i in 1:leng){
    randompois <- rpois(size, 6)
    taskmlepois[i] <- mean(randompois)
  }
  return(taskmlepois)
}
```

alternatively, you can initialize it explicitely as numeric of given length

```
taskmlepois <- numeric(size)
```

this also should improve performance. But basically, you can achieve what you want with a one-liner:

```
tapply(rpois(size*leng, 6), rep(1:leng, each = size), mean)
```

Since the draws from `rpois` are [i.i.d.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independent_and_identically_distributed_random_variables) sampling them sequentially does not change anything.